# Initialize Nim array with repeated value

Tags: arrays, nim-lang

I have this type with a few integer fields:

```
type
    Thing = object
        x: int32
        y: int32
```

I need to make a big fixed-sized array of these - with this type:

```
array[0..255, Thing]
```

How do I initialize this array with the x and y of all items set to 0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nim by default 0-init's memory so it's been done already for you. The [following](https://play.nim-lang.org/#ix=36FO) is all you have to do to see:

```
type
  Thing = object
    x: int32
    y: int32
var a: array[0..255, Thing]
echo a
```

Though say you wanted to set them to a different default you could do either versions of the following:

```
for x in a.mitems:
  x = Thing(x: 10, y: 10)

for i in 0..a.high:
  a[i] = Thing(x: 10, y: 10)
```

If you want to initalize an immutable you can always use a block stmt

```
let a = block:
  var res: array[0..255, thing]
  for x in res.mitems:
    x = Thing(x: 10, y: 10)
  res
```

Comment: can this be done without a `var` statement?